# How Would I handle letters being put in my Calculator in C++

Tags: c++

Hey guys haven't been programming for that long so I'm not great and I'm just now getting into error handling and exceptions and thing like that just started learning c++ which is a little different from others I have learned so was wondering if I could get some help here.

I started making a calculator and it went well but I ran into a problem if I input a letter in instead of a number for example if I input a+1 I want it to tell me that i have to enter a number or something like that..I already know ahead of time my code is probably messy so criticism is accepted not going to hurt my feelings. but anyways here is what i have so far

```
int main()
{

    double num1;
    double num2;
    char operation;
    char again;

    cout << "Welcome to Brent's Calculator.\n";
    cout << "Enter 'Value (operator) Value' ex. 2 + 2" << endl;
    cin >> num1 >> operation >> num2;
        cout << num1 << " "
            << operation << " "
            << num2 << " = ";

        do {
            switch (operation) {
            case '+':
                cout << num1 + num2 << endl;
                break;
            case '-':
                cout << num1 - num2 << endl;
                break;
            case '*':
            case 'x':
            case 'X':
                cout << num1 * num2 << endl;
                break;
            case '/':
            case '%':
                if (num2 == 0) {
                    cout << "You cant divide by 0" << endl;
                }
                else {
                    cout << num1 / num2 << endl;
                }
                break;
            default:
                cout << "not understood";
            }
            cout << "would you like to enter another calculation? (y/n) ";
            cin >> again;
            cin >> num1 >> operation >> num2;
            if (cin.fail()) {
                cout << "you need to enter numbers" << endl; //this part added mess with it tomorrow
                cin.clear();
                cin.ignore(999, '/n');
            }

            cout << num1 << " "
                << operation << " "
                << num2 << " = ";


        } while (again == 'y' || again == 'Y');

     //closing bracket of the else for cin.fail
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

and of course my if statement with the cin.fail isn't working

Comment: Why don't you just do input validation? Put it in a loop, and if the argument is a letter, just re-run the loop.

Comment: `cin` with stop reading and enter the fail state if any input that cannot be turned into a double is found where a double is expected. Sadly this will not protect you from something like "10g44" because `cin >> num1 >> operation >> num2;` will wind up with 10 g 44 for `num1`, `operation`, and `num2` respectively. @Ron has the right idea. Read the data as `string`s  and convert the `string`s. If the whole `string` is not converted, there's some crap in the `string` that's invalid.

Comment: this is a good idea I know what your talking about but not quite sure on how to implement it ill have to do some searching like I said haven't been doing this that long

Comment: Always, always, *always* do input a line at a time, since that's how the user sees it. Then you can use `std::istringstream` to parse within that line, in a much saner and understandable manner.

Comment: @o11c got it thanks for the tip will do some research on how to do that, not sure on how to do that and implement it into what I have now.

Comment: Read more about [parsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing) and [recursive descent parser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser). Compile with all warnings & debug info (`g++ -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...). **Use the debugger** (`gdb`)

Comment: @Geostalker `std::getline` (*not* `std::istream::getline`). Although TBH C++ streams are annoying sometimes, so I just use the C (POSIX) `::getline` a lot, too.

Comment: % is modulo operator and not division.

Comment: Also, why are you repeating the code before the loop at the end of the loop. Learn about DRY (don't repeat yourself) principle. It is even worst as you don't even do the same validation. Either move the code at a unique location or even better split the code in multiple functions.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your code to reduce it to a [mcve] of your problem.  Your current code includes much that is peripheral to your problem - a minimal sample normally looks similar to a good unit test: only performing one task, with input values specified for reproducibility.

Answer (score 1):

Your cin.fail isn't working because of  a small typo

> Multi-character character constant

```
cin.ignore(999, '/n');
```

it should be

```
    cin.ignore(999, '\n');
```

corrected code

Alright tried one more solution

So the idea is to use `continue` ..and garble the value of num1 and num2  for invalid value (only present sol for '+').I have used NULL but you can use any other garbled value you want

```
#include<iostream>
#include <math.h>       /* isnan, sqrt */    

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    double num1;
    double num2;
    char operation;
    char again;

    cout << "Welcome to Brent's Calculator.\n";
    cout << "Enter 'Value (operator) Value' ex. 2 + 2" << endl;
    cin >> num1 >> operation >> num2;
    cout << num1 << " "
    << operation << " "
    << num2 << " = ";

    do {
        switch (operation) {
            case '+':
                if ((num1 != NULL) && (num2 != NULL ))
                cout << num1+ num2 << endl;
                break;
            case '-':
                cout << num1 - num2 << endl;
                break;
            case '*':
            case 'x':
            case 'X':
                cout << num1 * num2 << endl;
                break;
            case '/':
            case '%':
                if (num2 == 0) {
                    cout << "You cant divide by 0" << endl;
                }
                else {
                    cout << num1 / num2 << endl;
                }
                break;
            default:
                cout << "not understood";
        }
        cout << "would you like to enter another calculation? (y/n) ";
        cin >> again;
        cin >> num1 >> operation >> num2;
        if (cin.fail()) {
            cout << "you need to enter numbers" << endl; //this part added mess with it tomorrow
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(999, '\n');
            num1 = NULL;
            num2 = NULL;
            continue;
        }

        cout << num1 << " "
        << operation << " "
        << num2 << " = ";


    } while (again == 'y' || again == 'Y');

    //closing bracket of the else for cin.fail
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Output After change

```
Welcome to Brent's Calculator.
Enter 'Value (operator) Value' ex. 2 + 2
44+44
44 + 44 = 88
would you like to enter another calculation? (y/n) y
a+b
you need to enter numbers
would you like to enter another calculation? (y/n) y
4+4.4
4 + 4.4 = 8.4
would you like to enter another calculation? (y/n)
```

Note: Corner case would be  when both entered number  is num1 =0 and num2=0 
0+0 = 0 (in that case better to use some other flag)

Comment: I got that far messing with it but after they enter ex a+b and they hit the you need to enter numbers i want them to be able to keep going without exiting first that's what I'm stuck on and thanks for the typo on the /n to \n didn't even notice that

Comment: @Geostalker presently it works for only + you will have to do similar for other operation

Comment: @ HariomSingh oh wow  would have never thought of doing that works like a charm now for what I need at this point in time. Thanks a lot really appreciate it.

Comment: You should not use NULL in modern C++ code. Either use 0 or nullptr as appropriate.

Comment: And neither `int(num1)` conversion.

Comment: @Phil1970 yes you are correct ..I would neither use o nullptr.I would rather use some other flag ...int(num1) it was a typo thanks fixed it